# Error while connecting to the mongodb Atlas from shared linux hosting server

Tags: node.js, shared-hosting, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect to mongoDB Atlas from my nodejs app its giving me the following error:

```
SERVER STARTED...
listening on port 'http://localhost:8080'
Could not connect to the MongoDB database. Exiting now... { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 13.234.134.161:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Also I have whitelisted IP on Mongodb Cloud (Atlas). I set it as 'Access to all' which is: 0.0.0.0/0

Same code is working fine on my local machine.

```
SERVER STARTED...
listening on port 'http://localhost:8080'
Successfully connected to the MongoDB database
```

The problem occurs when I am deploying my code to GoDaddy shared linux hosting server and trying to connect from there.

What's making difference...?

My nodejs code is:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);

var options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}

mongoose.connect(dbConfig.dbUrl, options, function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('Could not connect to the MongoDB database. Exiting now...', err);
        process.exit();
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully connected to the MongoDB database");
    }
});

const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log(`SERVER STARTED...\nlistening on port 'http://localhost:${app.get('port')}'`);
});
```

DB url is as follows:

```
dbUrl: "mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@cluster0-qsfll.mongodb.net/<DATABASE>?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

If anyone got the same issue and solved it, please write the solution here. Thanks :).

Comment: Did you change `<USERNAME>`, `<PASSWORD>` and `<DATABASE>` with your actual username, password and database in `dbUrl`?

Comment: Can you provide the  URL for the local database? 
Make sure mongod server is running

Comment: Yes I replaced <USERNAME>, <PASSWORD>and <DATABASE>with my actual username, password & database, and same DB URL I am using on my local machine.

Comment: Did you set username and password for your local db? if not then the local mongodb url should be `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/<DATABASE_NAME>`

Answer (score 0):

Just got the same issue.
Try to remove `useUnifiedTopology`.
Helped for me.

Comment: but after removing "useUnifiedTopology", I got deprecation warnings and errors { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-01-qsfll.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 13.234.25.74:27017]
    at Pool.